# Fixed precision for boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, boost

I have problem with boost::posix_time:

Here code:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime now(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time());
std::wstringstream record;
record  << now.time_of_day();
```

record shows: eg. "08:15:30.093750". It is correct. Exactly what I expect.
But sometimes I saw strange, eg. "08:15:32" in stead of "08:15:32.000000".
How to get "08:15:32.000000"?

Thanks in advance.

Solution:

```
std::wstringstream record; 
boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, wchar_t>* timeFacet(new boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, wchar_t>(L"%f"));
record.imbue(std::locale(record.getloc(), timeFacet));
record << now.time_of_day();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want non-default formatting you need to ask for it: http://www.boost.org/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html

Comment: It works:

    `std::wstringstream record;`
    `boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, wchar_t>* timeFacet(new boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, wchar_t>(L"%f"));`
    `record.imbue(std::locale(record.getloc(), timeFacet));`
    `record << now.time_of_day();`
`

Comment: @PetervanderSanden: You could also use the typedef `boost::posix_time::time_facet` to make it a bit shorter (and more robust probably).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hours, minutes, and seconds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration) accessors and format the output however you want.